# how to draw a part of a png image c#

Tags: c#, drawing, sprite-sheet

I'm trying to draw a part of a .png image but the code i found is not working. this is my code

```
        //define canvas
        canvas = pb.CreateGraphics();
        sPicture = new Bitmap(pb.Width, pb.Height);
        sCanvas = Graphics.FromImage(sPicture);

        // Create a Bitmap object from a file.
        Image image = Image.FromFile(@"");

        // Clone a portion of the Bitmap object.
        Rectangle cloneRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 11, 6);
        System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat format =
            image.PixelFormat;
        Image cloneBitmap = image.Clone(cloneRect, format); //Error: No overload for method 'Clone' takes2 arguments

        // Draw the cloned portion of the Bitmap object.
        canvas.DrawImage(cloneBitmap, 0, 0);
```

This is for a sprite sheet and thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use Clone(), you can do this directly with Graphics.DrawImage(). It looks like you are trying to do this in WinForms. If, so handle OnPaint for the control you want to draw on. In the example below I'm drawing directly on the form.

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics graphics = e.Graphics;

    int width = 60;
    int height = 60;

    // Create a Bitmap object from a file.
    Image sourceImage = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Mike\Downloads\logo.png");

    // Draw a portion of the source image.
    Rectangle sourceRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
    graphics.DrawImage(sourceImage, 0, 0, sourceRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
}
```

If you want to do this without WinForms, there is the extra step of creating the target Graphics instance.

```
    int width = 60;
    int height = 60;

    // Create a Bitmap object from a file.
    Image sourceImage = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Mike\Downloads\logo.png");

    // Create a drawing target
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, sourceImage.PixelFormat);
    Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);       

    // Draw a portion of the source image.
    Rectangle sourceRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
    graphics.DrawImage(sourceImage, 0, 0, sourceRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

    // Save
    bitmap.Save(@"C:\Users\Mike\Downloads\out.png");
```